# tool:udp debugging tool on solaris

Tags: debugging, networking, udp, solaris, netstat

I am looking for UDP debugger tool, for the following requirement

1) netstat -s, shows  udpInOverflows=23000 and this counter is increasing continuously.
   how can I check udp packets which are thrown because of no buffer space.

2) what are the possible reason for this problem to occur and how to solve it.

3) is there any way to check incoming UDP packet which are received by kernel after all verification like udp socket is open for that port and no check sum error, snoop will not work because it capture direct from network interface.

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to spend a little time with kernel source you should be able to use dtrace to get at the information you want.  For example "dtrace -n 'fbt::udp_input:entry{stack();}' will show you how packets are getting into udp_input (not all that interesting).  You should also check the mib::: probes and fbt:ip:ip_drop*:.  This is all dependent on the version of Solaris you are using of course.